# How to create Candlestick chart of google api

Tags: asp.net, google-visualization

I am to create a candlestick chart to show stock details from xml file in asp.net
please provide me any good link of example/tutorial of google's candlestick charts.

i got http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/compound_charts.html
link but dont know how to use this api in asp.net(vs2008) to show candlestick chart.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Api Chart can be used with a simple call link.
More explained here: http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html

Like the webside explain:

The preceding link is an example of a basic Chart API URL. All Chart URLs have the following format:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=<chart_type>&chd=<chart_data>&chs=<chart_size>&...additional_parameters...
```